# How can I remotely control my phone via android studio?

Tags: adb, remote-control, remote-access

I need to remotely control my phone from computer.

- My touch screen is not working
- My display is broken I can't see anything
- I have android studio and sdk's for my phone not sure which was needed but it was jellybean so downloaded all sdk's for that
- Phone is pattern locked but I can unlock it(muscle memory)
- Not sure if USB debugging is activated or not

**Phone**: Red Mi 2

**OS**: Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I doubt that remote control can be achieved without confirmation, and since your touch doesn't work.. How do you mean you can unlock it when touch doesn't work?

Comment: I feel vibrations sometimes while pattern lock is wrong and sometimes it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you can use an external USB-C keyboard to interact with the device. It is plug-and-play for newer Android versions.